# Kinds of integer overflow on subtraction

Tags: c++, integer, integer-overflow

I'm making an attempt to learn C++ over again, using Sams Teach Yourself C++ in 21 Days (6th ed.). I'm trying to work through it very thoroughly, making sure I understand each chapter (although I'm acquainted with C-syntax languages already).

Near the start of chapter 5 (Listing 5.2), a point is made about unsigned integer overflow. Based on their example I wrote this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main () {
    unsigned int bignum = 100;
    unsigned int smallnum = 50;
    unsigned int udiff;
    int diff;
    udiff = bignum - smallnum;
    std::cout << "Difference (1) is " << udiff << "\n";
    udiff = smallnum - bignum;
    std::cout << "Difference (2) is " << udiff << "\n";
    diff = bignum - smallnum;
    std::cout << "Difference (3) is " << diff << "\n";
    diff = smallnum - bignum;
    std::cout << "Difference (4) is " << diff << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This gives the following output, which is not surprising to me:

```
Difference (1) is 50
Difference (2) is 4294967246
Difference (3) is 50
Difference (4) is -50
```

If I change the program so that the line declaring `bignum` reads instead `unsigned int bignum = 3000000000;` then the output is instead

```
Difference (1) is 2999999950
Difference (2) is 1294967346
Difference (3) is -1294967346
Difference (4) is 1294967346
```

The first of these is obviously fine. <strike>The number `1294967346` is explained by the fact that `1294967346` is precisely `2^32 - 3000000000`. I don't understand why the second line doesn't read `1294967396`, owing to the 50 contributed by `smallnum`.</strike>

The third <strike>and fourth lines</strike> I can't explain. How do these results come about?

Edit: For the third line - does it give this result just by finding the solution modulo `2^32` that fits in the range of values allowed for a signed int?

Comment: Check your arithmetic, 2^32 = 4294967296

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2^32 - 3000000000 = 1294967296 (!)

Comment: 2^32 - 3000000000 is quite a bit smaller than 1294967296 factorial.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Could you give me some idea of how the third one happens?

Comment: The third one is technically implementation-defined.  But in practice, on a two's-complement architecture is that `bignum - smallnum` evaluates to 2999999950.  This is then assigned to a `signed int`, which will basically reinterpret the underlying bits without modifying them.  This results in -1294967346.  The C standard says that *"[if] the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the
result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised"*.